# Array de dados javascript para PHP

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa noite, para muitos é facil, mas não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho uma página de pedidos a qual tenho um campo com os produtos e a quantidade de cada um, ao clicar em adicionar ele mostra numa div um "preview" dos pedidos e os valores.

Quando eu clico pra enviar o pedido, ele só envia o que esta no dropdown de seleção e não a lista toda.

Queria saber como eu faço para enviar toda essa lista de produtos para a página php que vai ser a responsável por tratar desses dados.

Segue o formulário que estou usando http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/payment-form-with-total-preview

Ali tem os arquivos html e js

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado pessoal, tenham todos uma boa noite.

Answer (score 2):

Se o que tens montado está de acordo com o que essa demo do link, a adição dos produtos está a ser feita apenas ao nível do documento, ou seja, é o Javascript que está a criar elementos em *runtime*.

Agora, quando fazes submit de um formulário, há que entender que os únicos valores que vão constituir o payload do pedido são os inputs e selects **com nome** que existirem no formulário.

Da forma como descreves o teu problema, estou a assumir que o form que estás a usar para enviar para o servidor tem apenas o painel do lado esquerdo incluído e que o botão de adicionar é o submit.
Ora, isso não pode ser montado dessa forma. Esse botão de adicionar **não vai ao servidor**.
Da mesma forma que ele é usado para disparar código de manipulação do DOM por parte do Javascript, também tu podes criar os teus próprios inputs.

Considera a seguinte construção simples:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contador = 1;
    function adicionarItem() {
        var descricao = $("#descricao").val();
        var novoinput = $("<input/>")
            .attr("type", "hidden")
            .attr("name", "item" + contador)
            .val(descricao);
        var novodiv = $("<div/>")
            .html(descricao);
        $("#formenviar").prepend(novodiv);
        $("#formenviar").append(novoinput);
        contador++;
    }
</script>
<input id="descricao" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="adicionar item" onclick="adicionarItem()"/>
<form id="formenviar" method="post" action="qualquer_coisa.php">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar tudo para o servidor"/>
</form>
```

*(Vou assumir que usas jQuery, porque estou a assumir que usas Bootstrap (a julgar por a demo que linkaste))*

Isto é um exemplo rudimentar do que esse demo que mostraste faz:

- Manipula o DOM via Javascript
- Alimenta o form com inputs em runtime
- Envia tudo para o servidor em um **único pedido síncrono**

Correndo a construção, e adicionando 4 itens, podemos observar o seguinte num DOM inspector:

[image: O DOM do exemplo, com 4 itens]

Como podes observar, o Javascript preparou a sopa toda. Já temos um form com 4 inputs escondidos (*hidden*), que podemos enviar para o servidor normalmente.

Utilizando PHP no servidor, e fazendo um dump da array do _POST para este mesmo pedido, resulta no seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [item1] => teste 1
    [item2] => teste 2
    [item3] => teste 3
    [item4] => teste 4
)
```

Que prova que os quatro items foram passados correctamente para o servidor.
Agora só precisas de escalar o exemplo. Em vez de 1 valor por linha, deverás querer mais.

O importante a reter é que o botão de adição não faz parte do formulário que vai para o server e que o Javascript consegue manipular o documento.

Existem outras formas de alimentar o payload de um pedido, mas acho que ganhas mais se conseguires entender primeiro uma manipulação de documento simples como esta.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos, é muito complicado hehe, sou iniciante, não tem como eu fazer daquele modelo que eu passei, como o preview dos dois itens? Quantidade, produto, ou derrepente um loop.